# Is there a way to generate a list string within Python, without any other 3rd party packages?

Tags: python

this code generates a list of integers

```
dir_list = list(range(11))
dir_list
```

numpy could transfer each element to string type

```
import numpy as np

dir_list = np.array(dir_list, dtype=np.str)
dir_list
array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
      dtype='<U2')
```

is there a way to finish the job within Python, without any other 3rd party packages?

Comment: Yes of course there is. Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply map each integer to string using inbuilt `map` function and  `map` returns iterator so you can convert it into list.

`list(map(str, range(11)))` should do.

output:

`['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']`

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this way you can iterate over each element of range object and convert to str and store as list:

```
dir_list = [str(i) for i in range(11)]
>>> dir_list
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```